# VIsual Basic Application Passing Multiple Parameters

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pass more than one parameter in VBA for Excel but everytime I do I get a:

> Compile error:
>
> > Syntax error

```
Sub first(ByVal fOne As Integer, ByVal fTwo As Integer)

    If fOne = 2 Then
        MsgBox "fTwo"
    End If

End Sub

Sub second()
    first(2, 3)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `Call first(2, 3)` or you can `first 2, 3` or even `first fOne:=2, fTwo:=3` but you cannot `first(2, 3)`.

```
Sub first(ByVal fOne As Integer, ByVal fTwo As Integer)

    If fOne = 2 Then
        MsgBox "fTwo"
    End If

End Sub

Sub second()
    first 2, 3
    'alternate
    Call first(2, 3)
    'alternate
    first fOne:=2, fTwo:=3
End Sub
```

There is no problem passing multiple parameters to a sub if the syntax is correct.

Comment: Thanks this is great, as a quick follow-up is one of these a "preferred method" or are they all about equal?

Comment: Some coders don't like to use `Call`; they say it is obsolete. Doesn't make much difference to me but some say I'm obsolete too. A lot of code I provide here uses named parameters (third example) but that is for instructional purposes as much as anything else. Named parameters can help identify a single optional parameter out of order. It really boils down to personal preference but pick one and stick with it.

Answer (score -1):

You pass arguments to Sub, but you can pass arguments to Function only:

```
Function first(ByVal fOne As Integer, ByVal fTwo As Integer)

If fOne = 2 Then
    MsgBox "fTwo"
End If

End Function

Sub second()
    Call first(2, 3)

End Sub
```